# Strip dash from params - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

How can I strip characters from params? If my params look like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=><ActionController::Parameters {"search_fields_cont_any"=>"123-456", "category_eq"=>"", "created_at_gteq"=>"", "created_at_lteq"=>""} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"submissions", "action"=>"index", "page"=>nil, "per_page"=>nil} permitted: false>

params[:q][:search_fields_cont_any] => "123-456"
```

How can I modify the params so that it would look like this:

```
params[:q][:search_fields_cont_any] => "123456"
```

#### CONTROLLER

```
@q = Submission.submissions_for(user: current_user).ransack(filter_params(params[:q]))
```

#### Private method

```
def filter_params(params)
 params.require(:q).permit(:search_fields_cont_any)
end
```

Ideally I would modify the params in the private method. How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't `gsub` your friend here?

Comment: I think so, but where do I implement it?

Comment: do it in controller

Comment: Use [`String#delete!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-delete-21)—note bang—`params[:q][:search_fields_cont_any].delete!('-')` anywhere.

Comment: Why not just create a custom setter on the model instead of transforming the param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def filter_params(params)
  params.require(:q).permit(:search_fields_cont_any)[:search_fields_cont_any].gsub!('-','')
end
```

In console:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(q: {search_fields_cont_any: 'abc-def'})
 => {"q"=>{"search_fields_cont_any"=>"abc-def"}} 
params.require(:q).permit(:search_fields_cont_any)[:search_fields_cont_any].gsub!('-','')
 => "abcdef"
```

Or, as mudasobwa says (even better - saves you 1 character):

```
def filter_params(params)
  params.require(:q).permit(:search_fields_cont_any)[:search_fields_cont_any].delete!('-')
end
```

Again, in console:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(q: {search_fields_cont_any: 'abc-def'})
 => {"q"=>{"search_fields_cont_any"=>"abc-def"}} 
params.require(:q).permit(:search_fields_cont_any)[:search_fields_cont_any].delete!('-')
 => "abcdef"
```

Comment: undefined method `delete!' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f955f9c0fa8> Did you mean? delete

Comment: Sorry, needed to actually get the value for `search_fields_cont_any` in order to call `.gsub!` or `.delete!`. Edited.